# What is the round-trip cost for localhost Redis Db? Is it ignorable?

Tags: performance, redis

I planned to use Redis on Windows.

The server will include both Redis Db and IIS.

Is latency ignorable?

Comment: Why don't you measure this and see if it is ignorable *for your case*?

Comment: Could you offer any NoOp Redis Command ?

Comment: Unless you need to connect from multiple processes / servers, you might be better off using native data structures of your programming language instead of using Redis.  It will always be slower to connect to a different process.

Comment: It is true. But I planned to use Redis as whole db not only cache. So it can not be replacable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        RedisClient rc = new RedisClient("localhost");
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            rc.Ping();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

64 bit windows 7 i-5 2500K @3.9 GHz

for 100000 Ping 5.2 seconds. I think score will be better with Server's Ethernet Card.

Comment: A sane implementation of TCP will not use the network card when connecting to localhost.